# When using React-VR with Socket.io , I crash when importing socket.io-client

Tags: socket.io, react-360

I am trying to use React-VR with Socket.io. I am crashing when I try to import socket.io-client(v2.0.4). I have to browse through examples without coming up with a solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please put the actual code in the question, instead of images of the code? In order to diagnose this, we would need to retype the code in our own IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your socket.io calls in componentDidMount as opposed to the constructor would be the correct way of doing this I beleive.